# Cat hangs when attempting to read empty STDIN

Tags: linux, bash, cat, stdin

My script attempts to gather information that may or may not be present in STDIN at execution time, but cat hangs if the pipe is empty. How can I ensure that my script skips this step if this there is nothing in STDIN?

```
stdin=$(cat <&0)
```

Note that I am specifically not looking for any solutions that refer to /dev/, as I intend this to be usable in a chroot whether or not /dev/ has been mounted if possible.

Comment: I would be surprised if a chroot without _at least_ /dev/null was usable in production. There's a long way between "/dev mounted" and "/dev manually created with the bare minimum", anyway...

Comment: No solution but `cat -` or even a simple `cat` would do the same as your `cat <&0`.

Comment: @xenoid yes, I know. I tried all three, and they all produce identical results. <&0 is just leftover from playing around to see if I can make cat error out rather than wait.

Comment: By the way, I continued to play with it while waiting for an answer and discovered that it wasn't just hanging. It was looking for input from the console. This lead to to experimenting with heredocs to attempt to terminate cat if it has no input, but got an answer before getting far with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually while working with pipes and stdin, a depleted pipe has no special meaning. New data may still appear until there is an `eof` that closes the pipe. Your `cat` terminates at `eof` as expected. If there was no data before `eof`, only then you can say the stdin *was* truly empty.

Consider `sender | receiver`. It's not uncommon the `sender` is (much) slower than the `receiver`; in such case the `receiver`'s stdin is almost always depleted, but you hardly ever want to kill the entire pipe because of it. Therefore tools that exit on "empty" (depleted but not yet terminated) stdin are exceptions rather than standard.

In Bash there is `read -t 0` (`-t` is not required by POSIX). From `help read`:

> If `TIMEOUT` is `0`, `read` returns immediately, without trying to read any data, returning success only if input is available on the specified file descriptor.

By default `read` reads from stdin, so the exit status of `read -t 0` will tell you if the stdin is "empty". But beware! A command like

```
echo 1 | read -t 0
```

may exit successfully or not, because `echo` and `read` run simultaneously, not sequentially. To avoid this, your script should `sleep` for a while before `read -t 0`. Depending on where the stdin comes from, "a while" may be relatively long. Do something like this:

```
sleep 1
if read -t 0; then …   # process stdin here, you know it's non-empty
```

You populate a variable with data taken from stdin. Since storing binary data in a variable is not a good idea (read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278644/108618)), maybe your data is just text. If so, use `read -t` like this:

```
read -r -t 5 -d $'\0' stdin
```

Null character (which you cannot store in a Bash variable anyway) as a delimiter (`-d $'\0'`) will allow you to read any text (e.g. with newlines) to the `stdin` variable. After at most 5 seconds (`-t 5`) the command terminates, allowing your script to continue.

Another approach is with `timeout`. A basic example from my Debian:

```
timeout --foreground 5 cat | wc -c
```

(Replace `wc -c` with your code that parses stdin; it's just an example).

This should handle binary data just fine. If `cat` doesn't get `eof` then after 5 seconds it will be killed, so `wc` will get `eof` anyway and the line doesn't stall. The problem is `cat` will be killed regardless if it's processing any data at the moment. I imagine you want to get all the data, if only there is some, even if it takes more than 5 seconds. Improved version:

```
{ timeout --foreground 5 dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null && cat; } | wc -c
```

If the first byte appears within 5 seconds, `cat` will be triggered. It then will process any further input until `eof`, no matter how long it takes. Everything including the first byte (if any) will go to `wc`. If there is neither a byte nor `eof` in 5 seconds, `wc` will receive just `eof`; the line doesn't stall.

Comment: My input is indeed text, in case anyone is curious. It's a colon-delimited array of information about a user and/or host that may or may not contain a password, which is why optional stdin is important for my uses(no passwords permitted on command line). If there is no data on stdin, the script attempts passwordless authentication methods and looks for the rest of the information in the first argument instead.